# Extract time from datetime using Angular js

Tags: javascript, datetime, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to extract the hour and minute from the datetime(eg:2013-09-03 05:02:04) using Angular js.I have done like this.

JSON Data:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "PriorityPassReservation": {
                "site_id": "8",
                "id": "235907",
                "priority_pass_schedule_id": "4",
                "member_id": null,
                "member_guid": "8-853414",
                "reservation_dt": "2013-09-05 19:00:00",
                "checkin_dt": null,
                "reminder_sent": "0",
                "created": "2013-09-03 05:02:04",
                "modified": "2013-09-03 05:02:04",
                "status": "booked"
            }
]
}
```

HTML:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="priority in priorityDetails.data">
     <td class="no">{{ $index +1 }}</td>

  <td class="priority_time">{{priority.PriorityPassReservation.reservation_dt| date:' hh:mm'}}</td>

  </tr>
```

But it does not give the actual result.Does anybody knows the solution?

NB: `priority.PriorityPassReservation.reservation_dt` is a json string

Comment: Have you tried angular.fromJson to convert it to a deserialized string?

Comment: @David Chase no..I didnt do like that.Updated my question

Comment: well your problem is because you already have a date and time the filter wont work on your value, try just using a string anything with a ":" will throw an unexpected token error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue might be related to the angular date filter supporting only ISO8601 compliant date string formats. 
You can simply convert your date string to a date object.

```
<td class="priority_time">
    {{getDateObject(priority.PriorityPassReservation.reservation_dt) | 
    date:' h:mm'}}
</td>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.getDateObject = function(dt){
    /* convert to date object */
    /* return new Date(2013,8,3,5,2,4); */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Code Hater..Hope it will work,but how can i dynamically convert the date object

Comment: @Gopesh You can extract y, m, d, h, m, s by splitting your string and then passing them to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: Just for future reference, a commonly-used library for this task is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It can parse the date for you and much more!

Answer (score 0):

Time - 05:02:04 (0-24 format). Try to use 'hh:mm'. Or use time format Oct 29, 2010 8:40:23 AM (with AM).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but it doesnot work..Actually priority.PriorityPassReservation.reservation_dt is a json string